# For how many ones is $N =11\dots1$ prime?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $N=111\dots1$ ($n$ ones). For which numbers $n$ is $N$ prime?

$n \ne 1, 3k$ is all progress I have made!

Comment: All composite n does not work

Comment: If there are $n$ digits in the representation, the number can be represented as $(10^n - 1)/9$.

Comment: I would write $N$ as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^k $$. That way $n$ will be the number of digits in $N$.

Comment: I found out that $n \ne 4k$, where $k$ is a positive integer. The reason is that since $1111$ | $101$, $1111 1111$ (8 digits) can be represented as $1111 * 110011$, $1111 1111 1111$ (12 digits) can be represented as $1001* 111000111$ and so on.

Comment: The only $n$ I have been able to find that makes this prime (through limited trial and error) is $n=2$. Not a clue how to prove if this is the only answer though

Comment: You might want to see this @Edi: This question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485350/factor-10n-1) relates to this question as well.

Comment: Some primes of this form are known: https://oeis.org/A004023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a well-known open problem to establish whether there exist infinitely many Mersenne primes, i.e., primes of the form $2^p-1$ for some prime $p$.

This question is its analogue which replaces $2$ with $10$. Indeed, if $\frac{1}{9}(10^n-1)$ is prime then $n$ is necessarily prime because $\frac{1}{9}(10^m-1)$ divides $\frac{1}{9}(10^n-1)$ whenever $m$ divides $n$.

Edit: It can be checked that
$$
\{n\in [2,1000]: \frac{10^n-1}{9}\text{ is prime}\}=\{2,19,23,317\}.
$$
Michael Stoker points out in the above comments also this longer [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A004023) sequence.

A related MSE question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300805/when-is-the-number-11111-1-a-prime-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: There might not be infinitely many solutions, but can I ask do you know another solution to the (base 10) problem where $n \ne 2$?

Comment: @TobyMak I added you some other solutions ;)